# prevent XslPath parse of c:if test string

Tags: xslt

I am using XSL and I want to put a c:if out into my generated HTML,

```
<c:if test="${value=='yes'}">
```

but the test="" part of the tag is being interpreted as an XslPath and fials that parsing ...

Is there any way to escape or disable the test part of this as being an XslPath

Comment: Well, I tried it inside and outside of xsl:text tags, I tried using !CDATA and $#nnn; encodes etc .. nothing fixed it ..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is due to the fact that a pair of curly brackets within an attribute is considered by XSLT as specification of an AVT (Attribute Value Template).

In order to specify a real curly brace, it must be doubled.

**Use**:

```
 <c:if test="${{value=='yes'}}">
```

**Here is a complete transformation**:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
 xmlns:c="some:c" exclude-result-prefixes="c">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
 <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

 <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
     <c:if test="${{value=='yes'}}"/>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**When this transformation is applied on any XML document (not used in this demo), the wanted, correct result is produced**:

```
<c:if xmlns:c="some:c" test="${value=='yes'}"/>
```

Comment: Thanl you!! That fixed it, I presumed i was a small tweak but just didn;t know which one!!!